# disable/ remove value if select 1 is greater than select 2 without mysql

Tags: php

I want to disable values of "to" if the selected values of "from" is greater than or equal to it's value. I've seen tutorials similar to this but it includes ajax and mysql. but mine does not need any queries. thanks!

```
 echo "<select name=\"from\" id=\"from\" class=\"form-control\" onchange=\"myfunc()\">";
            echo "<option value=\"10\"> 10:00 AM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"11\"> 11:00 AM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"12\"> 12:00 NN </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"13\"> 1:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"14\"> 2:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"15\"> 3:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"16\"> 4:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"17\"> 5:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"18\"> 6:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"19\"> 7:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"20\"> 8:00 PM </option>"; 
            echo "</select>";

             echo "<select name=\"to\" id=\"to\" class=\"form-control\">";
            echo "<option value=\"10\"> 10:00 AM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"11\"> 11:00 AM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"12\"> 12:00 NN </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"13\"> 1:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"14\"> 2:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"15\"> 3:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"16\"> 4:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"17\"> 5:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"18\"> 6:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"19\"> 7:00 PM </option>";
            echo "<option value=\"20\"> 8:00 PM </option>";
             echo "</select>";
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Loops are too mainstream?

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript

Comment: I have a javascript here. Can somebody help me figure this out? the maximum value on the select 2 should be 20:

function myfunc()
        { 
          var e = document.getElementById("from");
          var strUser = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
          var f = document.getElementById("to");
          var text = '';
          
           for (var i = strUser + 1; i < strUser + f.options.length; i++)
            { 
              text += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+"</option>"; 
            }; 

            f.innerHTML = text; 
          }

Comment: @samantha.nicole I wonder why you chose to use PHP to echo out these strings instead of using plain HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much better if you use HTML instead of the PHP echo syntax.

The JS code you need to make it work is this one:

```
 function myfunc() {
     var from = document.getElementById("from");
     var strUser = parseInt(from.options[from.selectedIndex].value);
     var to = document.getElementById("to");
     for (var i = 0; i < to.options.length; i++) {
         if (to.options[i].value < strUser) {
             to.options[i].disabled = false;
         } else {
             to.options[i].disabled = true;
         }
     };
 }
```

It will disable all options in the second select equal or greater than the selected value in the first select and will enable all others. This way it will work for multiple selections from the first select.